# what's the rule about value attribute on li element in IE 11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

IE 11 with Windows 7 pro sp1 up to date

[image]

the problem is when I set the value of a li element to "1#ab", the "#ab" is been truncated, only "1" left, as following:

[image]

but if I set the value to "1a#b", everything is alright, as the following pics:
[image]

why this? I can't understand.
I've tried these cases in Chrome, both are alright.
the MS only said the value of a li element should be an integer, seems nothing more:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535124(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Inputs have value attributes, not list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML rule is that a [`li` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) may have the `value` attribute, if the element is a child of an `ol` element, and the value of the attribute must be an integer. HTML5 even prescribes rules for handling malformed values. In the case `value="1#ab"`, the value 1 shall be used and the rest be ignored. The result should be the same for `value="1a#b"`. However, error handling is known to vary in browsers; HTML5 is trying to remove the differences, but it’s a long way to go.

What you should use instead depends on what you are trying to accomplish. The current code is invalid in two ways: the `value` attribute is not permitted here at all, and if the element were a child of `ol`, the attribute value would be invalid.

If you are just trying to store data in an element, to be used in scripting, use a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) instead, e.g. `data-value`.