# Is this a bug? Jquery append method work on IE browser, pure value type is long will convert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I occur a weird problem on IE browser. Like this:

```
var HtmlTemplate = '<li value="{0}" name="{1}" {2} content="{3}" {5} {6}> <i class="glyphicon"></i>{4}</li>';
```

I will loop this HtmlTemplate. The li tag value is long value type. If this code work in IE, the value will converted,but Chrome and FF browser are worked fine. If I insert some string words, the IE is worked fine.

My question is : How to avoid IE convert this value? If you have any idea, please tell me, Thank you so much!

Please reference https://jsfiddle.net/j4zryLma/1/  The Li value is not true. If it running at IE browser. How to resolve it ?

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean.. can you give a sample on how this template is used... you need to share the template rendering code and a sample value that is causing the problem

Comment: How you are using `HtmlTemplate` variable?

Comment: OK. I will share some code at jsfiddle.net. wait a moment!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j4zryLma/1/   Please reference this code. If it running in IE browser, the value not ture. How to fix it? Chrome and other browser worked is fine.

Comment: @Satpal  I will loop some array, and set different obj value to HtmlTemplate . Finally, I will use Jquery append method add to container tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML attribute "value" is reserved for specific usages and should not be used to set random data like you did. I will quote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27855602/1517335) :

> The HTML rule is that a li element may have the value attribute, if the element is a child of an ol element, and the value of the attribute must be an integer. HTML5 even prescribes rules for handling malformed values.

For your problem, you have 2 solutions : use your `<li>` in a `<ol>` tag and use the value attribute for the order of the `<li>` in the list, or if you want to put custom data in the value attribute, use another attribute like `data-value` for example, which will not be altered by the browser, like IE does.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes. The name of value is special tag. I already changed tag's name. Thank you so much!